# Ruby 1.9 regex encoding

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding

I am parsing this feed http://www.sixapart.com/labs/update/developers/ with nokogiri and then running some regex on the contents of some tags.  The content is UTF-8 mostly, but is occasionally corrupt.  However, for my case I don't really care and just need to pass the right parts of the content through, so I'm happy to treat the data as binary/ASCII-8BIT.  The problem is that no matter what I do, regexes in my script are treated as either UTF-8 or ASCII.  No matter what I set the encoding comment to, or what I do to create the regex.

Is there a solution to this?  Can I force the regex to binary?  Can I do a gsub without a regex easily?  (I am just replacing &amp; with &)

Comment: you can easily pass a string to gsub string.gsub('&amp', '&')

Comment: Doing that just causes the string to become a regex.  Same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode the initial string and use the FIXEDENCODING option.

```
1.9.3-head :018 > r = Regexp.new("chars".force_encoding("binary"), Regexp::FIXEDENCODING)
=> /chars/
1.9.3-head :019 > r.encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` have a property of encoding. Try to use method `String#force_encoding` before applying regex.

UPD: To make your regexp be ascii, look on accepted answer here: [Ruby 1.9: Regular Expressions with unknown input encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942148/ruby-1-9-regular-expressions-with-unknown-input-encoding)

```
def get_regex(pattern, encoding='ASCII', options=0)
  Regexp.new(pattern.encode(encoding),options)
end
```

Comment: Right, I did that.  The problem is I can't get the regex to have the same encoding (binary) as the string.

Comment: @singpolyma, look on UPD. Is it what you need?

Comment: Right, I can get it to be ASCII or UTF-8, but can't get it to be binary/ASCII-8BIT