# String is .blank? but neither empty nor whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to use the squish method to reduce multiple white spaces in a string to single white spaces. However, I have a string with mutliple spaces which are not reduced. When I check for `string[space_position].blank?` it returns true, but its neither empty, nor does is it `== ' '`.

What could cause this behavior?

Not sure if this is relevant, but the string comes from a mongoDB and was saved there by Locomotive CMS.

Comment: Can you add 1) string before method call 2) args you are calling method with 3) what you would expect? This would make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: @Puhlze 1) The string is something like this: `string = "sth:   Sth"`. 2) Which method do you mean? I'm simply calling string.squish, no arguments. 3) I would expect squish to output `"sth: Sth"`, and `string[6] == ' '` to be true.

Comment: In the first code example of my above comment there are actually 3 spaces between the colon and the S.

Comment: provide output of `string.chars.map(&:ord)`.

Comment: @tokland: the three spaces: [32,160,32]. By the way, the spaces are created by `Sanitize.clean(string).to_json[1..-2]`.

Comment: what's the string you have and what output you want? example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the three spaces: [32,160,32]

ASCII 160 is a [non breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) usually found in HTML, and apparently not recognized as `squish` as a space. Try to replace it before:

```
string.gsub(160.chr, ' ').squish
```

Comment: Very clever, thank you. However I'm getting an encoding error (`Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)`). I did add `# encoding: utf-8` at the top of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: it works for me in a console (1.9.3). Try with `"\xA0`" or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942148/ruby-1-9-regular-expressions-with-unknown-input-encoding

Comment: Sorry, I've been off work for a while. Unfortunately, the issue still persists. I don't understand how the link you posted is supposed to help?
`string.count('\xA0')` returns 13 in my example. However, when I call `string.gsub!('\xA0')` nil is returned, meaning that nothing is replaced. Weird.

Comment: the link is supposed to help because you have ASCII-160 chars in your string, so it's good to know why those chars stand for. I don't understand that gsub! command you run, without the second argument. Ýou said your string was [32, 160, 32], right? in a console: [32, 160, 32].map(&:chr).join.gsub(160.chr, '').squish
 => ""

Comment: Sorry, the method I actually called was `string.gsub!('\xA0','')`, with second argument. Yes, what you write works. However, it doesn't with my string.

I think the error I pasted above means, that my string is UTF-8 but the regexp is ASCII!? I tried `string = string.encode('UTF-8')` and called gsub again, nothing different.

Calling `string.gsub("\xA0".encode('UTF-8'),' ')` leaves me with this error: `RegexpError: invalid multibyte character: /\xA0/`

Comment: I found the solution. The unicode for non-breaking spaces is u00a0. Thus I had to gsub /\u00a0/. Thanks for your help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588942/convert-non-breaking-spaces-to-spaces-in-ruby

Comment: Actually solved this with `string.gsub(/[[:space:]]/,' ').squish`

Comment: it worked with POSIX-style? and failed with `string.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string.squish!
```

This might modify the string itself. Also, any empty string like " ".blank? will return true.

Comment: This is not changing the output for me.